# Possible to add Event (Start Date and End Date)

Tags: ios, iphone

I am Using in this project FFCalendar. How Possible to add The Start Date and End Date for Adding The Events in FFCalendar. Please Tell me the Solution.

Default Calendar in Ipad
Example:StartDate Select - Today Date Time:05.30 AM
        End Date Select - 2014-10-29 Time:11.30 AM

but FFCalendar only Adding Events for Start Date only.. How possible to add the enddate (FFCalendar project) to Displayed the Events for Default Calendar(Please Refer Default Calendar). Please Tell me the Solution..

Refer this Link:((FFCalendar Project)
https://github.com/fggeraissate/FFCalendar

Answer (score 0):

here I see what you need in your source code.

```
- (NSMutableArray *)arrayWithEvents {
......
[event1 setDateTimeBegin:[NSDate dateWithHour:10 min:00]];
[event1 setDateTimeEnd:[NSDate dateWithHour:15 min:13]];
.......

return [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:@[event1];
}
```

hope that help !

Comment: k Fine. But End Date?.. See SetArrayWithEvents Method

Comment: you can see "setDateTimeEnd:[NSDate dateWithHour:15 min:13]"